# Positioning elements regarding only the parent container?

Tags: html, css

My agony about element's positioning continues:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
</div>

#div1 {
right:0; // what I want - it's right border should be 0px from the parent's right border, regardless of any other div inside.
}

#div2 {
bottom:0; // it's bottom border should be 0px from the parent's bottom border, regardless of any other div inside.
}

#div3 {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
// should be on the parent's center, regardless...
}
```

So, I want the parent to be the reference, and not the neighbors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this:

```
  #container {
  position: relative;
  }

  #div1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  }

  #div2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  }

  #div3 {
  margin: 0px auto;
  }
```

But this is solution you could find after 30 secs reading about div positioning...

Answer (score 1):

Just use CSS

```
position:relative;
```

Set this on `div1`, `div2`, `div3`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right solution cause relative positioning means you're positioning element relatively to its position, not parent's position.